# New "Sheriff" badge acting strange for Qiaochu

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I just noticed that I've received the new "Sheriff" badge for serving one year as a moderator. I got one copy of the badge (since I resigned a month before my second year would have started), but [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/307/sheriff?userid=232) seems to have received it six times:

> [image: Qiaochu Yuan with 6 Sheriff badges]

This is curious. <s>BTW, this badge doesn't seem to be listed on [the relevant meta.SE page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/161783).</s>

Comment: Heh... You're only supposed to get it once regardless of how many years. Obviously, Qiaochu turned up a loophole...

Comment: @Shog9: suggestion, change the text to "served as a moderator for at least 1 year". I was wondering when I will receive my second...

Comment: Hmmm. Sheriff and Constable. To get those I would need to travel back in time, and be a moderator for the first two years of the site's existence. But that would screw up the whole timeline and people will end up with lizard's tongues, and donuts will rain from the sky, or some other Simpsons Treehouse of Horror V "Time and Punishment" scenario. The most frightening of which is a baby speaking in Tulsa Doom's voice, uttering the most fundamental truth of our existence. "*This is indeed a disturbing universe.*" Wait, how did I get here?

Comment: It would seem that the Sheriff and Constable badges both got awarded to some people who had the diamond by virtue of working for SE rather than being mods.

Comment: @Isaac there may be a small number of former employees who received the badge because we don't have any easy way to tell who was an employee or for how long.  We excluded current employees from the badges.

Comment: @BenCollins: Having only 101 rep is a pretty good indicator here, as is having 0 questions/answers.  For Sheriff, you could probably compare to the election results lists, though I don't know that there's anything as readily available for Constable.  Perhaps looking at logged moderator actions?

Comment: @Isaac yep.  We'll basically be doing things like that to figure out who earned the badge by virtue of employment and adding the ones we missed to the exclusion list.  Qiaochu is an interesting case...still trying to figure that one out.

Comment: Well, it looks like the problem with ol' Qiaochu is there were multiple periods of moderatorship for him.  When I was working on the queries for this I generally discounted this scenario because it looked as though it only happened for employees which we are excluding from the badge award.  Looks like we found a counterexample.

Comment: @Asaf: It's Thulsa Doom. Tulsa is a city in Oklahoma, USA. "Tulsa Doom" sounds like a cowboy name, like "Texas Slim" (which I guess is appropriate in a thread where sheriff features prominently).

Comment: @Rick: I wrote that comment when I was just waking up... So that's my excuse. Also Tulsa Doom sounds less cowboy'ish and more supervillain'ish. It's the doom part, you know.